# Show that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : (n +1) ^{n+1} \ge 2 n ^{n+1}$?

Tags: inequality

I have tried many things but I seem to just go round and round without getting anywhere.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are the many things you have tried?

Comment: I have tried using the binomal theorem, tried to prove via induction, and tried in many ways to manipulate it in order to 'get it to work'. All those led me to no result I saw as progress, which is what I mean by - "I seem to go round and round".

Comment: Binomial theorem is enough. You should recheck your solution.

Comment: Note also that there is very often some slightly sneaky step when proving inequalities of this nature, whether you approach them via induction or the binomial theorem or something else---at some point you necessarily have to throw away or introduce some term to somehow make your expression "less precise" in order to approach the quantity you want. The hard part is being strategic about this imprecision.

Comment: Alt. hint: write it as $\,\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \ge 2\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get from applying the binomial theorem.

Rewrite the inequality as
$$(n+1)^{n+1}-n^{n+1}\geq n^{n+1}$$
Expand the left side to obtain:
$$\sum_{k=0,\dots,n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}n^{n+1-k}1^k-n^{n+1}\geq n^{n+1}$$
Or:
$$n^{n+1}+n\cdot n^{n}+\dots+1-n^{n+1}\geq n^{n+1}$$
The negative term cancels out and we obtain:
$$n^{n+1}+\sum_{k=2,\dots,n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}n^{n+1-k}1^k\geq n^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed it